# Securing accountsystem from external changes

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js

I just started my own little project with HTML5, PHP and Node.js.
Currently everything works just as i want it. But something came to my mind after checking the code. My website is supposed to be an auction house. I store the userid in my database and have the id as an id tag on the website.

Here is the problem. If someone now bids on the items, i just simply take the id and send it to my node.js server. Technically someone could just change this id to the id of another person registered. Currently i have no real solution to this problem, since this is my first website.

I thought about maybe inserting the phpsessionid cookie into the user database everytime the user logins and then send these with the userid to the database everytime he bids on an item. The node.js server would then compare the stored value with the send one to verify if the right user send the bid.
My question is now, is this a good solution or is there a better way?

Edit:
Some of the code:

```
<li class='dropdown' id='steam' title='".$steamprofile['avatarmedium']."' name='".$steamprofile['steamid']."'><a href='#'class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false' style='padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;line-height:50px'><img src='".$steamprofile['avatar'].">'><span class='caret'></span></a><ul id='profilenav' class='dropdown-menu'><li><a href='?logout'>Logout</a></li></ul></li>;
```

So this is the part that gets created once i login with openid

```
var steamid=document.getElementById("steam").getAttribute("name"); 
socket.emit('status added',{itemid:id, tmerid:timerid, steamid: steamid, avatar: avatarlink});
```

This is how i get the userid and send it to the node.js server

Comment: Why and how do you use PHP and Node.js together?

Comment: Why are you using both PHP and NodeJS? It seems unnecessary complex to have two backends - especially in your first app. You could issue a [JWT](http://jwt.io) that hold the user id on login, if you try to tamper with the data in a JWT it will be invalidated, so you can pass the token to NodeJS instead of passing the user id on its own

Comment: I only use php to get the items from my database, so i can display them on my site with jquery. I also use php when the user logins. So they dont actually work together. I use node.js for the bidding. I used to use php for this too, but then i realized that the calls to the server would be too much and i couldnt figure out a way to send the current price/owner everytime someone bids on the item. So i had to switch to node.js and socket.io

Comment: "Technically someone could just change this id to the id of another person registered"   This should *never* occur. If you need to change that id, simply delete his bid and add the other id. IDs should never be changed by users (Unless in one-to-many relationship, in which the house can be bid by only one person at time)

Comment: You really should have asked at that time. It seems unlikely that the calls would be too much and updating the price could also have been solved with interval polling. If all else failed then [sockets is very possible to use in PHP as well](http://socketo.me/)

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to prevent. But the stuff i had on my mind wouldnt really solve the problem, like echoing the userid into the javascript part. People would still be able to alter the id in chrome developer tools. So i thought i might update the sessionid everytime someone logins and then check these with the value stored in the database. So even if someone alters the id, he shouldnt be able to alter the sessionid to the right one. Would that work?

Comment: @JimL i will check that out. Since its solely for learning, its never too late to change the code :) Thanks

Comment: If you keep the current setup I'd look into using a JWT. You can find implementations for both [PHP](aaaaa) and [SocketIO](https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt/blob/master/README.md). As long as your PHP and NodeJS server share the same secret they will be able to use/validate the same tokens. Which can hold data (like a user id) which is non changable without invalidating the token

Comment: alright i will look into JWT. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: And what kind of IDs are we talking about? Math.random()/new Date, incrementing ints?  "random" chars? uuid? and wich implementation?

Comment: they are from the steam web api. People can log in into the site with their steam profile. To get the information i used a php based solution. Since anyone can get the corresponding steamid to every steam account, i need to use some from of verification. I will look into JWT to achieve this.